# How can i get post category name by post id in fishpig wordpress magento extension?

Tags: magento

I've installed the fishpig wordpress extension with magento. Here i able to show post Title, post date, author name and post content. But i can't show That particular post category name using this extension. So please someone help me to show category name on the POST PAGE.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried asking on http://magento.stackexchange.com/?